# Display error messages and fetched data in php from another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

So what I'm doing is this, basic registration form with some validation, which I don't really know it works because I don't know how to display these messages in an index file looking nicely, and thing is I'm aiming for single page application and form is getting submitted from a modal so I don't want to refresh the page while displaying messages.

I know it involves some ajax but i can't figure out a way to get these error messages from php file and pass it into a javascript file, for example if I assigned these header messages to a variable how would one go to getting this variable across a file because I don't want to repeat this validation and setting variables in the javascript as well, this may have a more simple answer but when I searched every tutorial was creating registration page in  another page completely or had php code in the index file  which I don't want to do,

```
<?php
include "../config/Database.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstname']));
    $lastname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lastname']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
    $username = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']));
    $pass = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pass']));

    if (empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    } else if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $firstname) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $lastname)){
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=char");
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {               
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=email");
        exit();
    } elseif (strlen($pass) < 8) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=pass8");
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=pass");
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=pass");
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=pass");
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$/', $username)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=username");
        exit();
    } else {
        header('Location: ../index.php?signup=success');
    }


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,email,uname,pass) 
            VALUES(:firstname,:lastname,:email,:uname,:pass)';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $result = $stmt->execute([':firstname' => $firstname, ':lastname' => $lastname, ':email' => $email, ':uname' => $username, ':pass' => $pass]);
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

a little edit here's the HTML form, in a modal, basically, you can see 2 divs 
with classes of success and error message and when I make an ajax call I want to display them accordingly

```
<form action="inc/register.php" target="myIframe" method="POST">
                            <h4 class="black-text">Registration</h4>
                            <div id="msgError" class="msg msg-error z-depth-3 scale-transition" style="display:none"></div>
                            <div id="msgSuccess" class="msg msg-info z-depth-3 scale-transition" style="display:none"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" class="validate">
                                    <div id="firstname_error" class="val_error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" class="validate">
                                    <div id="lastname_error" class="val_error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text" name="email" class="validate">
                                    <div id="email_error" class="val_error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" name="username" class="validate">
                                    <div id="username_error" class="val_error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" name="pass" class="validate">
                                    <div id="password_error" class="val_error"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" onclick="return myFunction()" id="submit" name="submit">Register
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn modal-close waves-effect waves-light">Cancel
                            </button>                         
                        </form>
```

and here's the ajax call which I tried to do it with

```
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/register.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      msgSuccess.setAttribute('style', 'display: ""');
      msgSuccess.innerHTML = "Signup Successful";
    }
  });
```

but i can't really display the errors accordingly to which error happens

Comment: You need `Json` in the mix. Your Php script should return data as json which can then be parsed by javascript

Comment: so, for example i would encode $result in a json unction if i'm not wrong and then parsing it in js file should work?

Comment: yes, javascript/jquey have methods available to parse `json`

Comment: in that case i should assign error messages in my php code to some variables and i can display them after parsing it on error: stage right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned earlier in my comment, you require `Json` to achieve your goal.
I've have made some additional tweaks to your PHP code which are also commented.
**Json response structure**

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [{
        "id": "msg",
        "msg": "Please correct the given mistakes"
    }, {
        "id": "firstname_error",
        "msg": "Invalid email entered"
    }, {
        "id": "username_error",
        "msg": "Username must be atleast 5 characters long & alphanumeric"
    }]
}
```

or

```
{
    "success": true,
    "errors": []
}
```

To achieve what we want, we must run all the checks individually then assign and return their return result via `Json` (which can be utilized in JS/jQuery).
We use an array `$data` that holds the validation status as well as the error messages and the css identifier of the element where the should be displayed.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
    include "../config/Database.php";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Checks whether the request type is `POST` rather than check if a field named `submit` is available

        // $data will be encoded as json and then returned by the script
        $data = array(
            'success' => false, // Flag whether everything was successful
            'errors' => array() // Provide information regarding the error(s)
        );


        $firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstname']));
        $lastname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lastname']));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
        $username = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']));
        $pass = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pass']));

        /* We will use individual `if` for all checks below, because
           `elseif` stops as soon as one of the conditions returns `true`
           and skips the rest of the validation checks, but we need to tell
           the user about all errors in one attempt and not one-by-one */

        if (empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pass)) {
            $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'msg', 'msg' => 'All fields are required'];
            // `id` should carry the css id of error div attached to field where the error originated from
        } else {
            $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'msg', 'msg' => 'Please correct the given mistakes'];
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $firstname) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $lastname)){
                $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'firstname_error', 'msg' => 'Numbers and Symbols not allowed in name'];
            }
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'firstname_error', 'msg' => 'Invalid email entered'];
            }
            if (strlen($pass) < 8) {
                $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'firstname_error', 'msg' => 'Password must use 8 characters'];
            }
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $pass)) {
                // I unified your password validation regex pattern
                $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'password_error', 'msg' => 'Password must be alphanumeric'];
            }
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$/', $username)) {
                $data['errors'][] = ['id'=>'username_error', 'msg' => 'Username must be atleast 5 characters long & alphanumeric'];
            }
        }

        // Execute only if there are no erros
        if (empty($data['errors'])) {
            // Validation complete without errors, do the required stuff here
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,email,uname,pass) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname,:email,:uname,:pass)';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $stmt->execute([':firstname' => $firstname, ':lastname' => $lastname, ':email' => $email, ':uname' => $username, ':pass' => $pass]);

            // Everything done, mark the registration as successful
            $data['success'] = true;
        }


        // Return the data with a `json` mime type instead of html
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        echo json_encode((object)$data);  // converts array into json

    }
?>
```

**jQuery Ajax code:**

```
$(".signupform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submitting with page refresh here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/register.php',  // php script's location
        type : "POST",
        dataType : 'json', // data type
        data: $(this).serialize(), // creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values
        success: function(data) {
            //Check to see if the validation was successful
            if (data.success) {
                //Turn the response msg into a success alert
                $('#msg').addClass('msg-info').text('Registration Complete');
                $('#msg').show(); // removes display:none property
            } else {
                //There were some errors
                //Turn the response alert into an error alert
                $('#msg').addClass('msg-error');
                // add `msg` to individual fields with there `id` in json
                $.each(data.errors, function(){
                    $('#' + this.id).text(this.msg);
                });
                $('#msg').show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

***Your html also needs slight tweaking*:**

1. Added a dummy class to form for targetting purposes
2. Removed unnecessary repetition of error message div

```html
<form class="signupform" action="inc/register.php" method="POST">    
     <h4 class="black-text">Registration</h4>
     <div id="msg" class="msg z-depth-3 scale-transition" style="display:none"></div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <input placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" class="validate">
       <div id="firstname_error" class="val_error"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <input placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" class="validate">
       <div id="lastname_error" class="val_error"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <input placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text" name="email" class="validate">
       <div id="email_error" class="val_error"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <input placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" name="username" class="validate">
       <div id="username_error" class="val_error"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
       <input placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" name="pass" class="validate">
       <div id="password_error" class="val_error"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Register
     </button>
     <button class="btn modal-close waves-effect waves-light">Cancel
     </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry For late response, thank you ^^ it helped me out